# How to exclude element from QuerySelector

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

```html
<h1>Product<span>4.0%</span></h1>
```

In the above HTML block, I would like to query and fetch the innerText of only the `<h1>` element, excluding the span element.

However

```js
document.querySelector('h1:not(span)').innerText
```

outputs: 'Product4.0%'

I would like the output to be: **Product**

Comment: `document.querySelector('h1').childNodes[0].textContent`

Comment: `h1:not(span)` searches for all `h1` elements that aren't, themselves, `span` elements (and thus makes no sense). It doesn't leave out the `span` in what it returns (which is good, what it returns is a direct link to the element in the DOM, and you wouldn't want a function called "query" to *remove* something from the page). If you want the text without the text of the span, you have to loop through the children of the `h1` and build up their text content, omitting the `span`.

Comment: If there is whitespace, filter the childNodes

Comment: @MathiasFossum - ***Wow***, how did I miss that [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is on Node, not Element?! Excellent!